# How to setup Helidon MP Server with https and TLS 1.2 only

Tags: helidon

How to setup Helidon MP Server with https and TLS 1.2 only ?

I didn't find it in Helidon MP Server documentation https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/introduction/01_introduction

Answer (score 1):

There is a [full writeup on how to do this](https://medium.com/helidon/http-2-and-tls-in-helidon-9801dc91b49d).